# Gerar código de barras

Tags: php

Gero uma imagem de código de barras da seguinte forma:

```
http://localhost/Cod_Barras.php?codigo=342342341 (Ocorre o erro, a imagem fica em branco)
```

Ou

```
http://localhost/Cod_Barras.php?codigo=34234234 (Gera a imagem normalmente)
```

Não sei qual é o problema o código gera alguns códigos e outros não.
Segue o código.

```
    <?php
/**
 * base criada por Aziz Vicentini
 * Modificado por Bruno P. Gonçalves @ Agência General de Desenvolvimento Web
 *
 * Baixado em: https://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/download/codigo/6491/
 *
 * Gera o código de barras
 *
 * @param string $codigo = Numero para gerar código de barras
 *
 */
function codificar($codigo) {
    $cbinicio = "NNNN";
    $cbfinal = "WNN";
    $cbnumeros = array("NNWWN", "WNNNW", "NWNNW", "WWNNN", "NNWNW", "WNWNN", "NWWNN", "NNNWW", "WNNWN", "NWNWN");
    $cbresult = '';
    if (is_numeric($codigo)&(!(strlen($codigo)&1))) {
        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($codigo); $i = $i+2) {

            $cbvar1 = $cbnumeros[$codigo[$i]];
            $cbvar2 = $cbnumeros[$codigo[$i+1]];
            for ($j = 0; $j <= 4; $j++) {
                $cbresult .= $cbvar1[$j].$cbvar2[$j];
            }
        }

        return $cbinicio.$cbresult.$cbfinal;
    }

    else return '';
}

function pintarbarras($mapaI25, $altura, $espmin) {
    $espmin--;
    if($espmin < 0) {
        $espmin = 0;
    }

    if($altura < 5) {
        $altura = 5;
    }
    $largura = (strlen($mapaI25)/5*((($espmin+1)*3)+(($espmin+3)*2)))+20;
    $im = imagecreate($largura, $altura);
    imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $spH = 10;
    for($k = 0; $k < strlen($mapaI25); $k++) {
        if (!($k&1)) {
            $corbarra = ImageColorAllocate($im,0,0,0);
        }
        else {
            $corbarra = ImageColorAllocate($im,255,255,255);
        }

        if ($mapaI25[$k] == 'N') {
            ImageFilledRectangle($im, $spH, $altura-3, $spH+$espmin, 2, $corbarra);
            $spH = $spH+$espmin+1;
        }
        else {
            ImageFilledRectangle($im, $spH, $altura-3, $spH+$espmin+2, 2, $corbarra);
            $spH = $spH+$espmin+3;
        }
    }
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}

// Recupera o código e cria a imagem jpeg
$codigo = $_GET['codigo'];
pintarbarras(codificar($codigo), 50, 1);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
```

Comment: Amigo dá uma olhada nesse artigo, acho que pode ajudar http://www.mundojs.com.br/2018/01/16/crie-codigo-de-barras-em-javascript-com-jsbarcode/

Comment: Preciso fazer isso usando php